# Copy List with Random Pointer - Copy not point to -

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I'm trying to solve the problem below:

A linked list is given such that each node contains an additional random pointer which could point to any node in the list or null.

Return a deep copy of the list.

The Linked List is represented in the input/output as a list of n nodes. Each node is represented as a pair of [val, random_index] where:

val: an integer representing Node.val
random_index: the index of the node (range from 0 to n-1) where random pointer points to, or null if it does not point to any node.

```
Input: head = [[7,null],[13,0],[11,4],[10,2],[1,0]]
Output: [[7,null],[13,0],[11,4],[10,2],[1,0]]
```

My idea was loop the head and create a new node with the same value and set it to my ans Node. It will be a copy because I'm creating a new one. Then, I loop again for the random pointer which looks in my ans Node the node with the value that I should point to. It works perfectly for the input above. However, if I have an input with duplicate values, the findeNode method might return an invalid Node. For example it fails for the input below:

```
[[3,null],[5,17],[4,null],[-9,6],[-10,3],[5,15],[0,11],[6,null],[-6,16],[3,16],[-6,11],[9,12],[-2,1],[-3,11],[-1,10],[2,11],[-3,null],[-9,7],[-2,4],[-8,null],[5,null]]
```

My output:

```
[[3,null],[5,3],[4,null],[-9,null],[-10,3],[5,15],[0,11],[6,null],[-6,13],[3,13],[-6,11],[9,12],[-2,1],[-3,11],[-1,8],[2,11],[-3,null],[-9,7],[-2,4],[-8,null],[5,null]]
```

Correct output:

```
[[3,null],[5,17],[4,null],[-9,6],[-10,3],[5,15],[0,11],[6,null],[-6,16],[3,16],[-6,11],[9,12],[-2,1],[-3,11],[-1,10],[2,11],[-3,null],[-9,7],[-2,4],[-8,null],[5,null]]
```

Node definition:

```
function Node(val, next, random) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = next;
    this.random = random;
};
```

My code:

```
var copyRandomList = function(head) {
    if(!head)   return head;
    
    let ans = new Node(0);
    let temp = ans;
    let cur = head;
    
    while(cur) {
        const node = new Node(cur.val);
        temp.next = node;
        cur = cur.next;
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    
    cur = head;
    temp = ans.next;
    while(cur) {
        const randomNode = cur.random;
        if(!randomNode) {
            temp.random = null;
        } else {
            const node = findNode(ans, randomNode.val);
            temp.random = node;   
        }
        cur = cur.next;
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    
    return ans.next;
};

const findNode = (list, val) => {
    if(!val)    
        return null;
    
    while(list) {
        if(list.val === val)    
            return list;
        list = list.next;
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Reference for problem description/runner for those unfamiliar: https://leetcode.com/problems/copy-list-with-random-pointer/description/